# Run a PHP code on 'ok', after using confirm()

Tags: php, javascript, confirm

I have this code currently:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" 
       onclick="return confirm('This is irreversible. Are you sure?');">
   <input type="hidden" name="act" value="run">
   <input id="btnDelete" name="btnDelete" type="button" value="Delete Selected"/>
</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['act']))
    {
        echo "<script>alert(\"sup\");</script>";
    }
?>
```

The alert is to check if it will run when i press "ok". It currently does not. I'm at my wits end, especially since I'm pretty much a noob at Javascript. If anyone can help it'll be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *sidenote:* `id` and `name` in submit button and your form are unnecessary in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a `type="submit"` to your submit button, and a `onsubmit` event to your `form`:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" 
   onsubmit="return confirm('This is irreversible. Are you sure?');">
  <input type="hidden" name="act" value="run">
  <input id="btnDelete" name="btnDelete" type="submit" value="Delete selected"/>
</form>
```